# Flutter: Using expansion panel with navigator animate the AppBar when expansion panel is open

Tags: flutter, state, accordion, navigator

In one section of a client's app an expansion panel / accordion is used to open some content. At the same time the AppBar is supposed to animated as is a new route has been pushed but the new route's content should display in the body of the expansion panel.

I have been able to implement this by creating an entirely independent Widget and using a state management library but it is not a tidy solution.

I wondered if it is possible to use the App's main Navigator but not remove the current route's body. This cannot be done with a nested navigator either as the AppBar uses Hero tags that are not reflected between Navigator's.

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using entirely customised state management.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter's in built Navigator, even Navigator 2.0, is well known to not be a particularly friendly interface to use, so I'd recommend the use of a community library that makes things easier.

[Auto Route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) is a popular solution that I use personally and can attest to its quality. For your particular problem it offers [navigation observers](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#navigation-observers) which you can register. You could use this to trigger the animation of your app bar when the new route is pushed.

It will be a little bit of effort to replace your current navigation with a new library but I'd imagine you'll end up with a cleaner solution at the end instead of customized state management.

Comment: I've taken a look and it seems like overkill for what I'm building. I have a partial solution using RiverPod as a state management library and an entirely custom Navigator. The RiverPod provider includes a number of fields including transitionType that can be changed dynamically and target which if set puts the body of the new page inside the target on the previous page. It's a bit inflexible and requires a lot of work but seems to be a better solution than fighting with Navigator API. What do you think?

Comment: This is a trade-off only you can decide I'm afraid. It depends how much you care about cleaning up your code vs the effort it will take to migrate your project to a new navigation solution. Even if you decide not to do it for this project, keep auto route in mind as I've found it is quicker to get started with even for small projects than the bare Navigator API

Comment: In retrospect I’m going to head your advice. Whilst I haven’t worked it out yet you are saying that this is possible to do and if he far more comfortable not limiting myself in the way I proposed above. Thanks. R

Comment: I would also be nice if I proof read my comments before pressing enter.

Comment: I should have stuck with your suggestion. In the past year I have implemented an entirely custom state solution before finding issues as the app expanded, built a Navigator extension before finding that deep linking was necessary, implemented and modified GoRouter before reaching its limitations. At least I know a hell of a lot about the codebase now. AutoRoute it is. Thanks, R